# Use PullToRefreshListView to implement Pull-to-refresh

Tags: android, listview

I use class [PullToRefreshListView](https://github.com/erikwt/PullToRefresh-ListView/blob/master/libraryproject/src/eu/erikw/PullToRefreshListView.java) to implement Pull-to-refresh.
And layout.xml as below:

```
<com.example.uidemo.PullToRefreshListView
    android:id="@+id/listView1"
    android:layout_width="400dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >
</com.example.uidemo.PullToRefreshListView>
```

And Activity as below:

```
PullToRefreshListView pdlv = new PullToRefreshListView(this);
pdlv.setOnRefreshListener(new OnRefreshListener() {

    @Override
    public void onRefresh() {
        pdlv.onRefreshComplete();
    }
});
pdlv.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_1,getData()));
setContentView(pdlv);
```

It works now.
But I set width 400dp, why it always show fill_parents.
How can I do to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can dynamic height and width on your own view class

```
pullToRefreshListView.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(width, height));
```